# SQL Distinct comma delimited list

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to create a comma delimted list of names in a table using the below query

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Name
FROM Production.Product
SELECT @listStr
```

This works fine, however the list does contain duplicates

Can anyone advise how I would make this `DISTINCT` so the list does not contain duplicates.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/15/sql-server-remove-duplicate-entry-from-comma-delimited-string-udf/ That article should prove extremely useful for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it useful ?

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + name 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM Production.Product) t
SELECT @listStr
```