# Getting a distinct comma-delimited string in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm stumped. Using SQL Server 2019.

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
  (1, 'Alice', 'Alice'),
  (2, 'Robert', 'Robert'),
  (3, 'Robert', 'Bob'),
  (4, 'Richard', 'Rich'),
  (5, 'Richard', 'Rick'),
  (6, 'Richard', 'Dick')
) tmp (ID, RealName, NickName)
```

Given this I'd like to produce a table which shows each user and their possible nicknames. I'd like to the result to be:

| Name | AKA |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | NULL |
| Robert | Bob |
| Richard | Rich, Rick, Dick |

There are other similar questions on SO that I looked into but don't quite solve the problem of omitting the Name from the AKA column. TIA

[SQL Distinct comma delimited list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832198/sql-distinct-comma-delimited-list)

[Produce DISTINCT values in STRING_AGG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646385/produce-distinct-values-in-string-agg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
with q as
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
  (1, 'Alice', 'Alice'),
  (2, 'Robert', 'Robert'),
  (3, 'Robert', 'Bob'),
  (4, 'Richard', 'Rich'),
  (5, 'Richard', 'Rick'),
  (6, 'Richard', 'Dick')
  ) tmp (ID, RealName, NickName)
)
select RealName, 
       string_agg(case when RealName <> NickName then NickName else null end, ', ') AKA
from q
group by RealName
```

outputs

```
RealName AKA
-------- ---------------------
Alice    NULL
Richard  Rick, Rich, Dick
Robert   Bob
```